# Terminate Java Program on Ctrl+Z input from user

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have following code:

```
        String inputString;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("jcp>");
            inputString = in.nextLine();

            String[] tokens = inputString.split(" ");
            switch (tokens[0]) {
                case "new":
                    createNewInstance(tokens);
                    break;
                case "call":
                    callMethod(tokens);
                    break;
                case "print":
                    Object obj = hashMap.get(tokens[1]);
                    print(obj);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Illegal command!");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I simply want the program to break out of while loop when user hits ctrl+Z

Comment: The easiest solution is to put this in a method and call `return`, or to check whether `inputString` is `null` (which it will be, and then you'll get an NPE when you try to `split` it). Also, unless you call `System.out.flush();`, your prompt won't get printed before the JVM waits for input.

Comment: As in, send an EOF with `cmd` under Windows? (that would be Ctrl-d with `sh`)

Comment: Ctrl+Z is a bad idea, because on Unix systems it's already used to suspend the program: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z

Comment: @FlorentBayle does not matter; this sequence will be "cooked" by the tty before it reaches the program. You cannot get raw keycodes in Java. Not without resorting to JNI anyway.

Comment: @chrylis There's nothing in the Javadoc to suggest it returns `null` at EOS.

Comment: @EJP You're right; I was thinking of `BufferedReader` instead of `Scanner`.

Comment: @FlorentBayle The OP appears to mean "the EOF character", which is Ctrl+Z on DOS/Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+Z to exit the program would be bad, Ctrl+C|Ctrl+D already ends the program execution on terminal, so it would be good the same way you expect users to type in commands, tell them to type `exit` as the command to EXIT your program and shortcuts like `x` or `e` can be used instead of complete word.

How about following code,

```
String inputString;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.print("jcp>");
    inputString = in.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = inputString.split(" ");
    switch (tokens[0]) {
        case "n":
        case "new":
            createNewInstance(tokens);
            break;
        case "c":
        case "call":
            callMethod(tokens);
            break;
        case "p":
        case "print":
            Object obj = hashMap.get(tokens[1]);
            print(obj);
            break;
        case "e":
        case "x":
        case "exit":
            return;
        default:
            System.out.println("Illegal command!");
            break;
    }
}
```

If `return;` won't work you can replace that with `System.exit(0);`

Comment: Considering there is no easy solution for my problem and it would also be not the right way to do it, i will just prompt user to press e or x  to terminate. answer accepted

Answer (score 1):

`nextLine()` will throw `NoSuchElementException` when the stream has reached its end. Or you can use `in.hasNextLine().`